# Hide bootstrap navbar brand and only display centered when navbar is collapsed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Perhaps the brand navbar button isn't the way to do this, but when I would like is when the navbar collapses and displays the toggle button I would like some text or the home page link to appear.

Like this:
[image]

I'd like the brand to be hidden when the navbar is not collapsed. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this certainly is possible. Can you show us your code? Or even better, a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do using some of the bootstrap utility classes. By default, the navbar collapses at XS (<768px).

To have something appear only when you get to XS just add the visible utility class for that size.

```
<div class="visible-xs"></div>
```

If you want something to show only when you are not in XS as the hidden utility class for that size.

```
<div class="hidden-xs"></div>
```

More info can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: It worked, screen resolution and media query is the key. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get both results, showing the brand just in collapsed navbar *and* having it centered (as per the question title), using the default Bootstrap navigation bar code example:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
```

edit it to:

```
<a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-block text-center" style="float: none;" href="#">Brand</a>
```

Two notes:

- `visible-xs-block`, as Marcelo said, sets the visibility just on xs devices, where the navbar collapses by default; the `-block` suffix is needed as of bootstrap v3.2.0 (simple `visible-xs` is now deprecated);
- `style="float: none;"` overrides the `float: left;` of the `navbar-brand` class that would prevent the `text-center` class to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ByShine/33sz6nrt/3/) fiddle for an example.
Change the resolution on the media query as required. You might need to edit the media queries for the navbar to get the match you need.

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width:1024px){
    .navbar-header {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
}
    .navbar-brand {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px){
    .navbar-brand {
        display: none;
    }
}
```